# Drone self-hosted, pipeline routing between Drone servers

Tags: drone.io

I have dev & prod kubernetes clusters with drone server in each. Both servers watching the same set of github repos.

I want to do smth like:

```
---
kind: pipeline
name: artifacts
drone_instance: dev   # <--- magic routing

steps:
  - ...
trigger:
  event: tag
  ref: refs/tags/dev-*

---
kind: pipeline
name: deploy_dev
drone_instance: dev  # <--- magic routing

steps:
  - ...
trigger:
  event: tag
  ref: refs/tags/dev-*

---
kind: pipeline
name: deploy_prod
drone_instance: prod  # <--- magic routing

steps:
  - ...
trigger:
  event: tag
  ref: refs/tags/prod-*
```

E.g. run different pipelines on different drone instances. I was looking at `platform` filter but it does not seem to be available in Kubernetes mode. Did anyone hack smth similar?

NOTE: corresponding gh thread https://github.com/drone/drone-runtime/issues/63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from drone.io team in Gitter:

> I recommend using .drone.yml for prod, and then creating a
>   .drone.dev.yml for dev. In your dev Drone instance, in the repository
>   settings, point Drone at the .drone.dev.yml